# php array_walk find key for value

Tags: php

First let me start off saying I'm brand new to php and winging it. I'm open to alternate methods for achieving the result and any criticism.

I've got a form with a list of country codes. The list is formatted so the country code is the value and the country is the text.

```
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
```

I'm wanting the country rather than the country code to be input into the database without having to change the html.

In the php file processing the form, I'm using `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS

```
$countryCode = htmlspecialchars($_POST["user_country"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

I put the country codes into an array as keys, and the name as values.

```
$countryArr = array('AF' => 'Afghanistan');
```

I created a variable to hold the name of the country

```
$country = '';
```

I created a function to find the value and write the key to $country

```
function countryName($value, $key) {
    if ($countryCode == $value) {
        $country = $key;
    } else {
        $country = 'not found';
    }
}
```

I walk the array using the above function

```
array_walk($countryArr, 'countryName');
```

The output I'm expecting is the country name or 'not found' but what I'm getting is an empty string.

What I've got now works in a playground, but not live, presumably because of `htmlspecialchars` - but I don't know how to handle that. I'm using `htmlspecialchars` as a way to escape the string, bypassing common XSS attacks

**Works in playground**

```
<?php
  $countryCode = 'AF';
  $countryArr = array('AF' => 'Afghanistan');
  $country = '';
  function countryName($value, $key) {
    global $countryCode, $country;
    if ($countryCode == $key) {
      $country = $value;
    } else {
      $country = 'not found';
    }
  }
  array_walk($countryArr, 'countryName');
  echo('Country:<br>');
  echo("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$country");
?>
```

Comment: Your `countryName` function doesn't have access to the `$countryCode` variable. Also, assigning values to `$country` within that same function doesn't serve any purpose. Can you rephrase what you're trying to do, as simply as possible? Do you want to pass a country name and retrieve the corresponding key?

Comment: I guess I don't understand scope in php... I would expect $countryCode to be a global variable as it's defined in the file scope outside of any function. I guess scope is different in php and I need to do more research. What I've got coming in is 'AF' but what I'm wanting is 'Afghanistan'

Comment: Yeah it would be the case in most languages. In PHP, you would have to either access it via `$GLOBALS['countryCode']` or declare it as global at the beginning of your function, with `global $countryCode;`.

Comment: Thanks, it works that way, but I always get 'not found'

Comment: I had key/value reversed in the function. Now it's working in a playground with a hard coded value but not live - presumably because of `htmlspecialchars` but I'm not sure how to handle that

Comment: What is the purpose of `htmlspecialchars` in your script/page? It should mostly be used if you want to display the value back to the user, but most likely not before that.

Comment: Escaping the string as an XSS bypass https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/prevent-xss-attacks-escape-strings-in-php/

Comment: Yes, but it only matters if you print the value back to the user's browser. Simply call it when you do so (when you output a variable within a view/template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments, you're simply looking for an array value given a key:

```
$countryCode = 'AF';
$countryArr = array('AF' => 'Afghanistan');

$countryName = $countryArr[$countryCode] ?? null;
```

The `?? null` part (requires PHP7) ensures `$countryName` will be null even if the country code doesn't exist as a key in the array.

Note that this is extremely basic PHP, I would recommend [reading up on the subject of arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: As I said, I'm just winging it right now. I managed to write a script that processes a form into a SQL db without learning about arrays. Life doesn't have to be from point A to Z in sequential order. I'll get there my way. Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return key from value, You don't need to create a function for that or use array_walk.
Instead this array_search will also work.

```
$key = array_search ('country_name', $countryArr);
```

Comment: Why are you passing a key to it? You want the value from the key or the key from the value? If it's the former, it's just a simple array access: `$countryArr[$countryCode]`...

Comment: @Jeto That works on playground and live. I'd like to give you credit if you want to put an answer up

Comment: @froggomad Just did.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$languages =
[
    'fr' => 'French',
    'es' => 'Spanish'
];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (
        isset($_POST['lang'])
        && is_string($_POST['lang'])
        && array_key_exists($_POST['lang'], $languages)
    )
    {
        $language = $languages[$lang];
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new Exception('Invalid language code.');
    }

    echo $language;
}

?>
<form method='post'>
    <select name='lang'>
        <?php foreach($languages as $k => $v) { ?>
            <option value='<?=$k?>'><?=$v?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```